# fopenのモードによるfwriteの挙動の違いについて

Tags: c

UnityのC#側でダウンロードしてきたデータをネイティブに保存するライブラリを作っています。

ファイルのオープン・クローズのタイムラグを減らしたいので、
iOS・Androidアプリ起動時はファイルをオープンしたまま閉じないようにしています。

ダウンロードファイルの実体はあるファイルに追加書き込みとなるため、

```
fopen(実体用ファイルパス,"a+b");
```

実体ファイルをハッシュ・位置・サイズを用いて管理するファイルは
Map形式なので全体書き込みとなるため、

```
fopen(実体管理用ファイルパス,"w");
```

としています。

上記、実体用ファイルはfwriteのたびにファイルの中身が更新されるのですが、
実体管理用ファイルはfwriteだけでは更新されず
fcloseしないとファイルの中身が更新されません。

**■質問**
　●ファイルの先頭から末端までをオープンしたまま
　　書き込む場合、どのようにすれば良いでしょうか？
　　（ファイルが巨大になっても良いようにできる限りfcloseを最小限にしたいです。）

●また、fwriteの内部の細かい仕様が記載されたページなどあれば
　　教えていただけませんか？
　　(どのモードの時は、ファイルにかかれるのか？メモリ上にしか持っていないのか？)

Comment: fwrite() の直後に fflush() を実行してみてはいかがでしょうか。`man 3 fflush` を参照してみて下さい。

Comment: fflush()で書き込む事はできたのですが、wにしているのに追加書き込みになってしまいます。
wモードの場合ファイルポインタが先頭からだと思っていたのですが、ファイルが開きっぱなしの場合、ファイルポインタが進んでしまうんでしょうか？

Comment: はい、fwrite() によってファイルポインタが書き込んだ分だけ進んでしまいますので `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);` などとしてファイルポインタをファイルの先頭に戻す必要があります。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

書き出してほしいタイミングで`fflush()`を呼ぶか、`setvbuf()`でバッファリングモードを指定してください。特に`_IONBF`を指定してバッファリングせずに常に書き出すよう設定することもできます。

`fwrite()`はバッファリングモードに従って書き込むだけです。

---

毎回同じ場所に書き込むのであれば一度しか書き込みができずバッファの意味がありません。"w"は開いた直後の状態を指定するだけで、永続的に状態が変化しないことを保証するものではありません。
`ftell()`、`fseek()`、`rewind()`、`feof()`、`ferror()`など基本的なストリーム処理について理解すべきです。

Comment: fflushで解決する事ができました。

バッファリングモードの件、大変勉強になりました、
なにも設定してないのでデフォルトで動作していると思います。
デフォルトを取得するメソッドのようなものが無いか検索してみたのですが
なさそうでして　_IOFBFではないかと思ってます。

おそらくオーバーヘッドを減らすため、バッファリングして書き込み回数を減らしているのではと思ってますが、このあたりは仕様を調査してみます。

Comment: １件だけでよしとしていたので、ダウンロードを１０件に増やしたところ
ファイルに追加書き込みになってしまい原因を調べています。
wモードの場合ファイルポインタが先頭からだと思っていたのですが、ファイルが開きっぱなしの場合、ファイルポインタが進んでしまうんでしょうか？